# How to use ethers keccak256?

Tags: ethers.js, signature, hash, keccak

I tried to use ethers' [keccak256](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ethersproject/keccak256) function like this:

```
import { keccak256 } from "@ethersproject/keccak256";

const signature = keccak256("balanceOf(address)");
```

But the script failed with this error:

> Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="balanceOf(address)", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.5.0)

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's look at the [function definition for `keccak256`](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/cf47ec5fd5c7e6dda4da499b1c25ac1d1cc84b5a/packages/keccak256/src.ts/index.ts#L7):

```
export function keccak256(data: BytesLike): string {
    return '0x' + sha3.keccak_256(arrayify(data));
}
```

The input is not a string - it's a `BytesLike` type.

With that in mind, here's how to rewrite the script to make it work:

```
import { keccak256 } from "@ethersproject/keccak256";
import { toUtf8Bytes } from "@ethersproject/strings";

const signature = keccak256(toUtf8Bytes("balanceOf(address)"));
```

The trick is to import another package from the ethers stack (`@ethersproject/strings`) that exports a function called `toUtf8Bytes`, which converts your string to `BytesLike`.

Answer (score 9):

With ethers.js v5 you can use:

```
const { ethers, utils } = require("ethers");

const labelhash = utils.keccak256(utils.toUtf8Bytes("example"))
```

This is documented [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/hashing/).

Comment: Installing the bespoke `@ethersproject/keccak256` package is better when you only need to use the `keccak256` function. You avoid installing all the packages that come with the umbrella `ethers` package.